# How to drop a particular key: value in the pandas.Series.value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key-value

Is there a way to drop a certain key on the `pandas.Series.value_counts()`

The `pandas.Series.value_counts()` below give a `frequency count` of the column `product`

```py
df_product = df.product.value_counts(normalize=True)*100

# This outputs: 
3    0.319474
4    0.280495
6    0.202842
2    0.091915
1    0.057584
5    0.047680
0    0.000010
Name: product, dtype: int64
```

However, since `0` is not what I want in the dataset, I would like to get rid of `0` from the result of the frequency count and not the main dataset before turning the `keys` and `frequency count` to a `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop any data like below:

I created data like `[0,2, 2, 0,5, 3, 4, np.nan]`
get count by `index.value_counts()`
and finaly drop `0` by `.drop(labels=[0])`

Here is final code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.Index([0,2, 2, 0,5, 3, 4, np.nan])
A=index.value_counts()
print(A)

A=A.drop(labels=[0])

print(A)
```

out put is like:

Before drop applied:

```
2.0    2
0.0    2
4.0    1
3.0    1
5.0    1
```

After Drop applied:

```
2.0    2
4.0    1
3.0    1
5.0    1
```

Comment: @A. J T based on your naming you have to apply drop on `df_product` like `df_product=df_product.drop(labels=[0])`

Answer (score -1):

pandas allows us to drop the elements of a Series based on specifying the index labels. Check out pandas.Series.drop official docs at :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html

Comment: pandas.Series.value_counts() returns a series. If you want to remove an entry from a series, you use series.drop(). I can't see where it could go wrong, could you share how you got the aforementioned series and your expected output?